# Caching Ajax response

Tags: ajax

I am trying to cache the result of a JQuery. This is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
     url: myEndPoint,
    type:"GET",
    cache:true,
    startTime: performance.now(),
    data: {"query": myQuery,
    "output": "json"},
    success: createDisplay,
    error: myError
    });
    console.log('After .ajax');
    };
```

I am trying to do this so that I minimize the amount of Ajax calls as I noticed that it takes about 2.4s to get the results which results in a lag time on the web user interface. In the networks console window I can see that the query is being re-executed even if it has been performed before. What am I doing wrong? Can I see the cached contents anywhere?

Comment: Look at the response header to the Ajax call. What does the `Cache-Control` header say?

Comment: This is what I got: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store

Comment: That's what I suspected. There is no way you can make the browser store this Ajax response, because the headers forbid it. But you could still store the result in a variable in your JS code and reuse that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can store it on localStorage.
There is also a library that does just that: [cache4.js](http://%20https://github.com/cityxdev/cache4.js)

It is a wrapper for the jQuery ajax call. Just pass to it what you would pass to $.ajax.

[EDIT]  Sure Simas Joneliunas Although I can guarantee that the docs will stay the same, as I own the repository. 
Using the question example, it would be something like this:

```
cache4js.ajaxCache({    
    dataType: "json",
    url: myEndPoint,
    context: {
        startTime: performance.now()
    }
    data: {
        "query": myQuery,
        "output": "json"
    },
    success: createDisplay,
    error: myError
}).then(function (res){
   console.log('After .ajax');
});
```

Comment: It would be polite to prvide a usage example of the library instead of just linking to the site. Documentation and sites change fast and your answers value cannot be guaranteed to stay